# Sensor for very low temperature (liquid nitrogen)

Tags: temperature-sensor

I'm looking for a way to measure temperatures in range of 40 to -200 °C (100 to −320 °F). The usual solution DS18B20 works only down to -55 °C (-67 °F).

Any ideas?

*p.s.* 
Precision of 2 °C would be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a K-type thermocouple (the most common type).

They have a range of around -200°C to +1350°C (depending on probe).

Alternatively a Resistive Temperature Device (RTD) can be used, since these have a typical range of around -240°C to 650°C with higher accuracy.

This might be of help to you: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/C50FA55B3B2F85D9862572D00083350E

Comment: I found on adafruits this board: Thermocouple Amplifier MAX31855 breakout board (https://www.adafruit.com/products/269) so for fast solution I'll try to built something around this board. In long term PT100 is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search on "cryogenic temperature sensors" and found these from [Lake Shore Cyrotronics](http://www.lakeshore.com/products/Cryogenic-Temperature-Sensors/Pages/default.aspx) – the price is shocking. It appears that you can use [silicon diodes](http://www.lakeshore.com/products/cryogenic-temperature-sensors/silicon-diodes/dt-670/Pages/Overview.aspx) as cryogenic temperature sensors, so you might be able to use less expensive parts if you don't need a ton of accuracy.